# Don't know why condition in the for statement executing in android

Tags: android

on clicking the button the 'x' value is storing in array[0][0]. But in the check method both if statements in the for loop are exicuting , i don't know  why the conditions are exicuting.
So i put a dialogue box in the if statement, while i am giving the array[0][0] to setMessage
it printing "x", But if i am giving the array[i][j] it printing the null value even both i and j values are zero.
i don't know what is the problem.

```
package com.example.tictactoe3;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.AlertDialog;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String array[][]=new String[3][3];

void check(String array[][])
{
    int i=0,j=0;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<1;j++)
        {
            if(array[i][j]==array[i][j+1])
            {
                if(array[i][j]==array[i][j+2])
                {
                    AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

                    dlgAlert.setMessage(array[0][0]);
                    dlgAlert.setTitle("Tic Tac Toe");
                    dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                    dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
                    dlgAlert.create().show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button bt1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        boolean value=true;
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            bt1.setText("x");
            array[0][0]="x";
            check(array);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Try to debug your code, it's the easiest way to understand where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For strings, you should compare using

```
if (strOne.equals(strTwo))
```

or

```
if (strOne.equalsIgnoreCase(strTwo))
```

Not using "==" operator

So replace

```
if(array[i][j]==array[i][j+1])
```

with

```
if(array[i][j].equalsIgnoreCae(array[i][j+1]))
```

and

```
if(array[i][j]==array[i][j+2])
```

with

```
if(array[i][j].equalsIgnoreCase(array[i][j+2]))
```